Specifying only one of a group of parameters is required in a TypedDict
Below is an example of a TypedDict:
class A(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: int

How to specify only one of the two parameters need to be provided while maintaining the TypedDict/
i.e. if a is provided b is not required and vice versa.
I can put both marked as Optional or not required but then I run into exception since one of those two parameters is needed. I am trying to find the cleanest way of specifing.

I doubt that this can be done using TypedDict.
If you do not mind adding a dependency, you could do this using Pydantic.
It allows you to add testing logic at different stage of the validation of your data, and comes with some features better describe on the documentation.
Your issue could be solved with something like this:
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator
from typing import Optional

class A(BaseModel):
    a: Optional[int] = None
    b: Optional[int] = None

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def check_exactly_one(cls, values):
        a, b = values.get('a'), values.get('b')
        if (a is None and b is None) or (a is not None and b is not None):
            raise ValueError('Exactly one of "a" or "b" must be provided')
        return values


You can use a union of TypedDicts:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
from typing import TypedDict, NotRequired

class _A1(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: NotRequired[int]

class _A2(TypedDict):
    a: NotRequired[int]
    b: int

type A = _A1 | _A2

d1_1: A = {'a': 1}          # fine
d1_2: A = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}  # fine
d1_3: A = {'b': 2}          # fine
d1_4: A = {}                # error

Note that it's NotRequired, not Optional. Optional[T] is short for T | None.
For more complex relationships, this would be rather verbose. However, I believe there are currently no better ways.
